# Connecting to a Mac with MS-RDP 3389?

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop

Is it possible to configure or connect (with or with out software) that helps us emulate the 3389 RDP that Microsoft has for Windows, but on the Mac?

I am a Major PC guy, but I am finding needs to connect to Mac computers often to configure them. And Apple Remote Desktop doesn't seem to be simple or doable to configure. Plus I would rather use a 3389 RDP application anyway.

Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know nobody has ever managed to properly reverse engineer all the ins and outs of the RDP protocol.
It is notoriously difficult because of subtle differences from Windows version to Windows version.
Implementing this on another OS with a totally different display architecture is even worse, because RDP is very closely tied to the way Windows handles things behind the screens.

And you don't really need it (or Apple Remote Desktop for that matter).
OSX contains a VNC server as standard. They call it "Screen sharing" but it is just a VNC server. Just enable it, configure security as desired and you are good to go.

Comment: Regarding your RDP claims - that is not actually true :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Non-Microsoft_implementations . Moreover, the protocol itself is properly documented: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh871750.aspx

Comment: Aqua Connect and iRapp (now bankrupt) both create an RDP server on OS X.  Haven't tried Aqua but iRapp was worlds faster than VNC.

Answer (score 1):

Having once labeled myself a "Major PC guy", you will do yourself a tremendous favor in the long run to consider re-inventing yourself into "Colonel Cross Platform". Hey, consider it a promotion.

In all seriousness, an open mind will help you appreciate and understand the differences. That said, you can use VNC (many different flavors available for Windows) to connect to a Mac quiet easily. The first thing to do is enable screen sharing on the Mac and you can do this from the command line (meaning also in a script or with `ssh`)

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -off -restart -agent -privs -all -allowAccessFor -allUsers -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw passw0rd
```

Then fire up your VNC client of choice and connect with the password of `passw0rd`. A tip I remember from a while back was to keep logout of your current user on your Mac before connecting. Otherwise you'd be prompted for a Mac login password after connecting but the desktop wouldn't render.

Comment: Thanks, I also like both platforms as there is so much more to learn.  Especially as a programmer.  I love being open minded.

Comment: Also, I will check out that command if I can't get xrdp working.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use RDP and cannot use the alternatives people proposed in their answers, there is a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125792/os-x-rdp-server-application).
The two answers there are use either [iRAPP](http://www.coderebel.com/products/irapp), but as I understand it you must use their client as well, or using [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/), which you may have to compile from source (I found [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-control-your-mac-using-win-rdp-client-xrdp-compiling-guide-on-osx.1770325/) relatively recent tutorial for that).

Comment: Along this line of thought, you *could* use logmein.com or other similar solutions but why pay for something you can already do?